# Where are SoapUI project level setup/teardown scripts stored?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I recently setup my new laptop and I need to find tear/load scripts for one of my SoapUI projects.

I'm using a community version 5.6.0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I thought the tear down/load scripts are embedded within your SoapUI project XML files.

Comment: Yes @Chris - using the good old notepad++ I was able to find them in the project :)
But the problem is that I cannot find them through UI ??
Maybe I should pаraphrase the question?

Comment: This https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/scripts.html was the second hit from Google for "SoapUI teardown script". :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had this question for long time.

Here you find them.

`Double click on the project => Click on Test Suites Tab => Look down`, both are available.

[image: Please look at the marks]

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for them in the wrong place - in TestSuite instead at project level :)